# how to solve Couch db conflict while replicating database to server to local

Tags: node.js, couchdb, pouchdb, couchdb-mango

we have couch server to local and local to server replication. after creating or updating a record for someday the collection will be in updated state after one or two day some collections will be updated previous state this causing conflict in the records. this conflict is happening to for some collections only remaining documents will be unchanged.
what is the issue for record overwritting?
is there is anyway or any api to automatically select conflicted record as winner?

Comment: See this article: [PouchDB Conflicts](https://pouchdb.com/guides/conflicts.html)

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB picks a winner for you - you can't choose which revision *is* the winner but you can delete any other revisions that you no longer need, leaving  your chosen winner as the only surviving revision.

For more information on conflicts and how to deal with them, see [this blog post](https://blog.cloudant.com/2018/07/25/Removing-Conflicts.html).